# Emacs Ctr-V does not view next screen but express "kill ring is empty"

Tags: terminal, emacs, linux-mint, cinnamon

I am using Emacs on Linux Mint Cinnamon 20.  Normally when pressing the key binding Ctr-V it should view next screen; however, when I press it the mini-buffer say "kill ring is empty".  How do I fix it?

This problem only occur in terminal version of Emacs, but the application version is fine.  By the way it is Emacs 26.3

Comment: Sounds like you have `cua-mode` turned on, or similar. Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Drew - The problem only arise with the command `emacs -nw` but not with the application version of the Emacs.  In addition, there seems nothing wrong with .emacs initialization file since I added only a few commands.  Unless `emacs -nw` use different initialization file from the application version.

Comment: @Thomas - It not the problem with mini-buffer.  I would expect emacs to scroll down the main frame.

Comment: `emacs -nw` should use the same init file. Try this in both the terminal and the GUI version and see if you get different results: `C-h k C-v` (where `C` is shorthand for `CTRL`).

Comment: @Thomas Solved.  I found the cua-mode enable command in one of the initialization file.  Thanks.

Comment: Great. But how come `cua-mode` was only enabled for `emacs -nw`?

Comment: You can add an answer for your own question. (And you can accept your own answer.) On the other hand, if you think the Q&A won't help others, you can consider deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from `cua-mode` is being activated.  In the initialization file just remove `(cua-mode t)` or change to `(cua-mode f)`.  Alternatively, you can just switch off by toggle `M-x cua-mode` but this only work during the session.